# How do I view model data after fetch in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm kind of new to backbone coming from knockout.js and I'm trying to get over this simple hump. I have this code:

```
$(function(){
    window.Student = Backbone.Model;

    window.Students = Backbone.Collection.extend({
         model: Student,
         url: 'test.php'
     });

    window.students = new Students();
    window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#container'),
        initialize: function() {
            Students.bind('reset', this.render);
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log(Students.toJSON());
        }
    });

    window.appview = new AppView();

 $('#test').click(function(){
     //var students = new Students();
         students.fetch();
        var q = students.toJSON();
        console.log(q);
    /*    
        students.create({
            name: 'John',
            grade: 'A'
        }); */
    })
});
```

My server sends the following JSON:

```
 [{"id": "1233","name": "Karen","grade": "C"},{"id": "1234","name": "Susan", "grade": "F"}]
```

When I click the button and look at the console in Chrome, I see:

First Click:

```
[] - Corrected -just an empty array
```

Second Click:

```
[
Object
  grade: "C"
  id: "1233"
  name: "Karen"
  __proto__: Object
, 
Object
  grade: "F"
  id: "1234"
  name: "Susan"
  __proto__: Object
]
```

First question is why does it take two clicks? Second: How can I simply assign/bind the grade(both as a collection and by id) to a textbox,  `<li>` or other UI element(better yet make it observable when ajax pops in).

Comment: Use `window.Student = Backbone.Model.extend({});` instead of your original line, because you are assigning the `Backbone.Model` object itself this way. Also see [Backbone.ModelBinding](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding) plug-in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The console message you are seeing is from the click event handler. The console message from the render method never gets called.

You don't see anything in the first log message because `fetch` is an asynchronous method, so when you call `toJSON` right after `fetch`, the collection hasn't been populated from the fetch method yet.

There are a couple changes you need to make to your code to get it work as expected.

First, you need to pass in the collection when you instantiate the view

```
//original
window.appview = new AppView();
//new
window.appview = new AppView({ collection: window.students });
```

Then within the view you need to bind to the reset event on the collection that was passed in to the constructor. (You have to bind to an instantiated object, and not the definition of an object like you were originally doing)

```
    window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#container'),
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
        }
    });
```

Now comment out the console log message in your click event, then you will only have to click once, and you will see a console log message from the render method.

```
 $('#test').click(function(){
     //var students = new Students();
        students.fetch();
        //var q = students.toJSON();
        //console.log(q);
    /*  
        students.create({
            name: 'John',
            grade: 'A'
        }); */
    })
```

Comment: Very well written answer. If anybody wants to play with the working code - **[HERE it is](http://jsbin.com/awahog/2/edit#javascript,live)** .

Comment: I got: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined
window.AppView.Backbone.View.extend.renderindex.php:85
Backbone.Events.triggerbackbone.js:115
_.extend.resetbackbone.js:479
_.extend.fetch.options.successbackbone.js:492
f.Callbacks.njquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery.min.js:2
wjquery.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d

Comment: @Len change `this.model` inside `render` to `this.collection`. Also see my link in the comment above.

Comment: ok, dzejkej's answer solved the issue. Thanks Paul too! This is a very practical example to use in everyday webpages. I have a reason to use backbone now in any project. The backbone "ToDo" example is a bit of overkill in most cases...

Comment: A backbone model won't trigger a "reset" event when the fetch is complete, you might want to try the change event.